# rails - does a change_column migration affect existing constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

If I have a field and it already has had a migration to set `:null => false` and I then do another migration to add `:unique => true` - do I now need to list the existing `:null => false` also in the new migration?
If I do not list it in the new migration does that imply it actually gets removed?

Answer (score 0):

all migration changes are relative to current database state, you don't need to list all existing changes from the beginning.

Good way to became sure is simply perform a test. gl

Comment: sounds good.  Before I can upcheck, please answer: - so how do I remove a constraint (other than rollback)?  I had thought that when I looked at the traditional 'downs' they just omitted the value, no?  btw I am also posing this for others :)

Comment: if you have defined up migration `change_column`, down one should be the same with reverse action explicitly specified

Comment: say a column has 6 existing constraints (db already existed).  How do I write a new (i.e. up) migration to drop just one constraint?

Comment: absolutely not sure, that answer is still actual. anyway: in your case you should `change_column` enumerate all valid constraints except deprecated one